# Amplified Fragment Length Polymorphism (AFLP) primers

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics

I am trying to blast AFLP primer sequences to the genome to find the locations of the AFLP markers. However, I can't seem to find full alignments for the primers on the genome.

For example, in the paper "[AFLP fingerprinting of the human genome](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs004390000438)", Human Genetics,  108(1):59-65, Table 1 reports 100's of location of each primer pair:
[image]

Now the MseI primer is GATGAGTCCTGAGTAA. So the M-CAA primer should be GATGAGTCCTGAGTAACAA. When I blast this on the reference human genome at NCBI, the results show the best alignment only covers 6-21 of the query:

```
Homo sapiens chromosome 7, GRCh38.p2 Primary Assembly 
Query  6          TGAGTCCTGAGTAACA  21
                  ||||||||||||||||
Sbjct  148723256  TGAGTCCTGAGTAACA  148723241
```

However, there should be close to a thousand matches for MseI-CAA across the genome according to the table. Does AFLP not require the whole primer to be matched?

According to the original AFLP paper, ["AFLP: a new technique for DNA fingerprinting"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC307397/), NAR 1995, the figure 1, the whole primer is being aligned.
[image]

Cross-posted to [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/175054/).

Update: One needs to use the digestion enzyme recognition site to map the AFLP markers. Example: http://insilico.ehu.es/AFLP/info.html

Comment: @TalhaIrfan please see [these guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) on tags - you've been adding a lot of very narrow and new tags

Comment: @rg255 Thanks RG! I would dare to disagree a bit and I still believe Biology SE needs more tags (_I haven't added any of tag blindly_). Like BCI wasn't even a tag week ago. Similarly ncRNA and lncRNA must be tags as many researchers want to work with them. GRCh37 and GRCh38 maybe narrow to biologists, but they are important for a bioinformatician.

Comment: @rg255 Having said that, I have still revised the guidelines in order to ensure I am serving the community. Thanks again!

Comment: Just that things like `ncrna` and `lncrna` are likely to be better served under a more broad tag like `rna` or `noncoding-rna` - people don't follow hundreds of tags but may subscribe to a handful of favorites (e.g. I follow `evolution` but wouldn't follow the tag `evolution-in-the-jurassic-period` if it existed)